# Let $T = \frac{X}{S}$ with X a random exponential variable of parameter lambda and S gamma random variable

Tags: probability

Let $T = \frac{X}{S}$ with X a random exponential variable of parameter lambda and S gamma random variable of this form: $\Gamma(2,\lambda)$.

I want to find the density of T. Know, I tried to find $F_T(t)$, so that I can derive and obtain the desired result. This is what I did:

$$ F_T(t) = \mathbb{P}[T \leq t] = \mathbb{P}[\frac{X}{S} \leq t]$$

Then I am not sure if I should write S = X + Y with X and Y independent random variable of exponential distribution $\lambda$ or if I should continue with the definition.

I tried to keep going with the definition:

$$ \mathbb{P}[\frac{X}{S} \leq t] = \mathbb{P}[X \leq tS] $$ 
However now I cannot say that this is equal to $F_X(tS)$ because I have S as random variable, so I tried to write it in this way:
$$\mathbb{P}[X \leq ts \ \vert S = s]$$
So that I can use Bayes theorem and write: 
$$\frac{\mathbb{P}[X \leq ts \cap S = s]}{\mathbb{P}[S = s]}$$
However here I am not sure on how to proceed. Any idea?

Comment: I suppose $X$ and $S$ are independent?

Comment: I have that S = X+Y, but X and Y are independent. @J.G I read that but did not get it.